# how can i exclude or include certain lines

Tags: regex, expect, cisco

this is the output of cisco command `SWEs-elmPCI-A-01#show cdp neighbors`

```
Capability Codes: R - Router, T - Trans Bridge, B - Source Route Bridge
                  S - Switch, H - Host, I - IGMP, r - Repeater, P - Phone,
                  D - Remote, C - CVTA, M - Two-port Mac Relay

Device ID        Local Intrfce     Holdtme    Capability  Platform  Port ID
SWEx-elmPCI-A-02.lssh.com
                 Gig 2/0/1         137             R S I  WS-C3750X Gig 1/0/1
SWEx-elmPCI-A-02.lssh.com
                 Gig 2/0/1         138             R S I  WS-C3750X Gig 1/0/1

SWEa-elmPCI-02   Gig 1/0/4         169               T    AIR-LAP12 Gig 0
SWEa-elmPCI-01   Gig 1/0/9         170               T    AIR-LAP11 Gig 0
```

how can i get only lines containing only lines with `SWEx-elmPCI-A-02.lssh.com` and its details `Gig 2/0/1         137             R S I  WS-C3750X Gig 1/0/1`

NOTE:there is space before `Gig 2/0/1         137             R S I  WS-C3750X Gig 1/0/1`
and `Gig 2/0/1         138             R S I  WS-C3750X Gig 1/0/1` and `S - Switch, H - Host, I - IGMP, r - Repeater, P - Phone,`
 and `D - Remote, C - CVTA, M - Two-port Mac Relay`

**i can use expect or ciso regex.i am using expect script to do some task on cisco so i can use some commands over there also (like include,exclude) or in my expect code.i just need to search for SWEx and its coressponding entries like Gig 1/0/4 so that i can put
Gig and 1/0/4 in some variable and use it for the each SWEx.. line**

Comment: What language are you using to do the Regex?

Comment: i can use expect or ciso regex

Comment: i dont know much about tcl but i suppose tcl regex would work for expect as well

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work:

```
/^(SWEx-elmPCI-A-02\.lssh\.com)\s+(.*?)\s{2,}(\d+)\s+(.*?)\s{2,}([^\s]+)\s+(.*?)$/gsm
```

Will create 6 groups:

1. Device ID
2. Local interface
3. Holdtime
4. Capability
5. Platform
6. Port id

---

### [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eI6kH5)

---

### Matches

**MATCH 1**

1. `SWEx-elmPCI-A-02.lssh.com`
2. `Gig 2/0/1`
3. `137`
4. `R S I`
5. `WS-C3750X`
6. `Gig 1/0/1`

**MATCH 2**

1. `SWEx-elmPCI-A-02.lssh.com`
2. `Gig 2/0/1`
3. `138`
4. `R S I`
5. `WS-C3750X`
6. `Gig 1/0/1`

Comment: thanks but it did not work for me but i got upto this on cisco command line `show cdp neighbors | include ^(SWE|[ ]+G)` SWEx-elmPCI-A-02.ikea.com
                 Gig 2/0/1         173             R S I  WS-C3750X Gig 1/0/1
SWEa-elmPCI-02   Gig 1/0/4         162               T    AIR-LAP12 Gig 0
SWEa-elmPCI-01   Gig 1/0/9         135               T    AIR-LAP11 Gig 0